# Why I get a location string when requiring a html file in webpack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack, frontend

```
var uib = $uibModal.open(
  {
    template: require('./create/create.html'),
  }
)
```

I want get content in create.html and show it in modal,but it shows `./create/create.html`,the string of the location in modal.

I've add html loader in webpack.config.js:

```
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'raw-loader',
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `templateUrl`

```
var uib = $uibModal.open({

  templateUrl: require('./create/create.html'),

});
```

when you want to declare html code in your `js` that time you can use `template`
but if you want to call html page like `create.html` that time you have to call it by `templateUrl`

also you can write code in `template` like :-

```
var uib = $uibModal.open({

  template: '<html><h3> Hie i am in js </h3></html>'

});
```

Comment: I've seen another project require a html file in my way and it works,I don't know why

Comment: Is there a way to get raw content in html in js?

Comment: see if you use `template` then you can declare html code in it like `<html> <head>...... <body>..` and all you can declare in template
but when you use to give path of any html then use `templateUrl` so it will give access to that particular page